# Angular charts bar chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-chart

I am currently working on representing data on bar chart using angular charts.

The records are like 54000, 5, 23000, 7, 23, 2344.For low numbers, bars aren't coming up.

How to represent neatly without having clumsy with numbers on Y-axis.

Comment: This might be so because when you compare 5 or 7 or 23 with 54000 and 2344 they are very very small. So you can get very low bar (hardly seen) for that.

Comment: Can we do y-axis values as Power of 10?

Comment: Even if you do so, do you think it will decrease the gap much between smallest and largest value.